# dropdown error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of adapting the selectpicker code which is in Jquery to Native JavaScript
i got this problem since 3 weeks, that I don't know how to resolve it

[dropdown default focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC2tG.png)

[focus blue background that I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6Fx.png)
-normally the focus should be on the first element, but we must click on the 'keydown' button before the focus is on the first element,
-also I would like to use the focus with the blue background, not the default dropdown focus

in add, I get this error every time I do a keydown

```
dropdown.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')
    at new hi (dropdown.js:97:34)
    at hi.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:65:41)
    at HTMLUListElement.dataApiKeydownHandler (dropdown.js:418:31)
    at HTMLDocument.n (event-handler.js:118:19)
```

this link of my code:
https://gist.github.com/ZoubaGate/f7bd2cba2f40643dce45863d135e04b0

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: 3551 lines of code... can you post the JavaScript code associated to this problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem is here: `this.button = this.dropdownHtmlElement.querySelector('button');`. There's probably no `button` inside `this.dropdownHtmlElement`.

Comment: I don't know exactly which line produces the error.
for those who want to test the code here is the css and the associated html:

https://gist.github.com/ZoubaGate/f7bd2cba2f40643dce45863d135e04b0



`<select class="dinf-selectpicker" data-selected-text-format="count">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
`

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn to use your debugger to determine which line is causing the error. If the `<select>...` you posted above is the only relevant html, then there is no parentNode to retrieve and that's the problem. But I suspect there is more at play.